# How to properly control the context when using d3.json event handler

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, anonymous-function

I am trying to implement an asynchronous request with d3.js inside self-executing anonymous function.

Rather than saying `d3.json(url, callback)`, I use `d3.json(url)` to first create the request object, then register a "load" event listener with `xhr.on` before starting the request with `xhr.get`.

Here is an example, in my object I have a render function that does render charts.  I would like to call this render function once my data are loaded from an API.
The call is made properly but inside my render function i am not able to call my `parseData` function.  It seems that I have lost the `this` context.

The console throw this exception : `Uncaught TypeError: this.parseData is not a function`

Does I make something wrong ?  Thanks

```js
(function() {
  var Ploter = {
    render: function(jsondata) {
        this.parseData(jsondata); // where the error is raised
        // draw the line chart
        // ....
    },

    parseData: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    init: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        var self = this;
        d3.json(this.DATAURL)
            .on("load", this.render)
            .on("error", function(error) { console.log("failure!", error); })
            .get();
    }
 Ploter.init();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the function directly, you can wrap it in another function, creating a closure. The inner function will be able to reference the value you stored in `self`, which refers to the original `Ploter` you're looking for:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var self = this;
    d3.json(this.DATAURL)
        .on("load", function(data) { self.render(data); })
```

Comment: Thanks, the closure solve my problem.  I am just not clear why the context is lost.  Is it related to the `get()` ?

Comment: @michael thanks for the edit suggestion - noticed I'd missed it myself, tried to change it and Stack Overflow said told me I hadn't made enough changes to improve it!! Maybe your suggested edit conflicted with mine, but that seems crazy

Comment: @Michael I was also going to add that into the answer, basically inside the callback, `this` refers to the underlying `d3.xhr` object. The `render` function doesn't have a reference to the object containing it, it's just an anonymous function that you have assigned to the `render` property of the object. When you call `x.myFunc()`, it assigns `x` to `this` inside `myFunc()`, but when it's invoked as a callback as in your code, it's equivalent to if it was calling `xhr.render(data)`... hope that makes sense